# Adjective clauses and PP phrases

Tags: prepositional-phrases, relative-clauses

> Brands often have clearly defined images or ‘personalities’ created by product advertising, packaging, branding and other marketing strategies that focus on positioning a product a certain way or by certain groups of consumers adopting the product.

"Or by certain groups of consumers adopting the product"

Does "or by certain groups of consumers adopting the product" follows the verb "created"?

And this sentence contains an adjective clause,between "consumers" and "adopting ", the pronoun "who" can be inserted without affecting the meaning, and it represents consumers.
Is that correct? which makes the sentence:

> Or by certain groups of consumers who adopt the product.

---

> Since people act out many different roles, they may modify their consumption decisions according to the particular
>   ‘play’ they are in at the time.

"according to the particular play they are in at the time"

The sentence also contains an adjective phrase, between "play" and "they", the pronoun "which" can be inserted, and it represents the phrase "the particular play", being the complement of the preposition "in", is this correct?

> the particular play which they are in

And the PP "at the time", does it go with

"they may modify their consumption decisions"

or the relative clause " the particular play they are in"?

Or they both work grammatically, but one makes more sense?

Comment: It's a coordination of two preposition phrases functioning as complements of "created", as bracketed here:  "Brands often have clearly defined images or ‘personalities’ created [by product advertising, packaging, branding and other marketing strategies that focus on positioning a product a certain way] [or by certain groups of consumers adopting the product]."

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for the answer, and does "consumers adopting the product" equal to "consumers who adopt the product" ?

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning, though the grammar is different: " ...adopting the product"  is a gerund-participial clause, while "... who adopt the product" is of course a relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ thank you so much for answering the question :)